# generator-angular-fullstack and angular-chart.js not displaying charts

Tags: javascript, angularjs, chart.js, angular-fullstack, angular-chart

I have been using angular for a while but this is the first time I have tried using yeoman and generator-angular-fullstack. I am trying to use angular-chart.js to display a chart in a view. poll.html loads up with no issues and displays everything correctly with only the chart not showing. Devtools shows status 200 on all documents and I can see that chart.js, angular-chart.js, and angular-chart.css are all being loaded in the correct order. I've attempted to use sample data to see if it was some sort timing issue but the sample data does not work either. Below I have listed the steps taken as well as code snips. Full source: https://github.com/MichaelLeeHobbs/freeTheVote

Thanks in advance!

I used Daftmonk's generator-angular-fullstack for the seed. Next I used bower to install angular-chart.js (bower install --save angular-chart.js)

index.html

```
  <script src="bower_components/Chart.js/Chart.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular-chart.js/dist/angular-chart.js"></script>
```

app.js

```
angular.module('freeTheVoteApp', [
 'ngCookies',
 'ngResource',
 'ngSanitize',
 'ngRoute',
 'ui.bootstrap',
 'validation.match',
 'chart.js'
])
```

poll.controller.js

```
angular.module('freeTheVoteApp')
.controller('PollCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
   var self = this;
   this.polls = [];

   $http.get('/api/polls').then(function(response) {
     self.polls = response.data;
   });

   $scope.options = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
   $scope.votes = ['3', '5', '13'];
});
```

poll.html

```
<navbar></navbar>
<!--
  ownerId: Number,
  name: String,
  options: [String],
  votes: [Number],
  active: Boolean
-->
<div class="mainContent container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-sm-6" ng-repeat="aPoll in poll.polls">
        <h3>{{aPoll.name}}</h3>
        <ol>
          <li ng-repeat="options in aPoll.options">{{options}}
            <span> votes: {{aPoll.votes[$index]}}</span>
          </li>
        </ol>
        <canvas id="{{'doughnutChart' + $index}}" class="chart chart-doughtnut" chart-data="votes" chart-labels="options"></canvas>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<footer></footer>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directive element should be have `data` instead of `chart-data` & `labels` instead of `chart-labels`

```
<canvas id="{{'doughnutChart' + $index}}" 
  class="chart chart-doughtnut" 
  data="votes" 
  labels="options">
</canvas>
```

And the data should be two dimensional array

```
$scope.options = [['a', 'b', 'c']];
```

[**Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/SYgfQTTEC2XD1OA0ZReV?p=preview)

Comment: Something odd is going on. I was able to use your plunkr example to display a bar chart on poll.html but have not been able to do the same for the doughnut chart. I've been trying to use the example on this page: http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/#getting_started  As to remove chart- this will throw a warning: "data" is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. Please use "chart-data" instead. You have put me on the right track, thanks!